# Oracle 11g installation failed on ubuntu 16

Tags: dpkg, oracle

I am facing append error after issue this command to install the Oracle 11g software product:

```
sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

Error:

```
msr@msr-Aspire-E1-531:~/Downloads/Disk1$ ls
oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm  oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb  response  upgrade
msr@msr-Aspire-E1-531:~/Downloads/Disk1$ su
Password: 
root@msr-Aspire-E1-531:/home/msr/Downloads/Disk1# sudo dpkg --install oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
dpkg: regarding oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb containing oracle-xe:
 oracle-xe-universal:i386 conflicts with oracle-xe
  oracle-xe (version 11.2.0-2) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing oracle-xe
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

Please share your solution to resolve it.

http://www2.hawaii.edu/~lipyeow/ics321/2015spr/installoracle11g.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to install the package `oracle-xe` but it conflicts with `oracle-xe-universal:i386`. You can only have one of them installed. If you want to install `oracle-xe` you need to remove `oracle-xe-universal:i386` first (with your favourite package manager):

```
sudo apt remove oracle-xe-universal:i386
```

Comment: How to remove the oracle-xe-universal:i386 from the package, Please share me the steps.